# The name Smtp does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, smtp, system.net.mail

For some reason i am recieving Smtp does not exist in the current context, im using the name space 'using System.Net.Mail;'. I have no idea why and have tried using System.Web.mail;. Hope you can help.

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();

                SmtpMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                mail.From = "";  //Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'    

                mail.To = "";   // Error    2   Property or indexer 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.To' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only   
                                // Error    3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection'  


                mail.Subject = "password";         
                mail.Body = "test";           
                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.brad.ac.uk"; // Error   4   'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' does not contain a definition for 'SmtpServer' and no extension method 'SmtpServer' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

                SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

Comment: please indicate where the compiler is stopping?

Comment: I don't see any bare identifier `Smtp` in that snippet... did you miss something when copying?

Comment: where are you instantiating the SmtpClient()?

Comment: Do you recieve `Smtp does not exist` or `SmtpMail does not exist` ?

Comment: The SmtpMail class seems to be obsolete, according to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx

Comment: Add such line in the function: `SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();`

Comment: If you are using .NET 2.0 or later, use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Answer (score 3):

SmtpMail is marked as obsolete in newer frameworks. SmtpClient is the recommended class. Maybe this is causing your issue?

EDIT: you can either point to a lower framework in your project, or swap out the class. Either one should work for you. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx)

EDIT: This class was last supported in .Net 1.1 It will give a complier warning in every framework afterwards.

Comment: using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient;
Non of the above work for some reason.

Comment: What framework is your project targeting? Did you add System.Net.Mail as a reference in your project? Just 'using' a dll isn't enough.

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't targeting a client framework. I don't think .Net.Mail is part of the client framework set.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing a reference to System.Net.Mail in your project. Add it in as a reference and see if that gets you further.

EDIT: Fixed reference to get to System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a `System.Mail`.

Comment: Thats what ive tried to do, there is no System.Mail in the references.

Comment: Im certain im missing some sort of assembly reference tho.

Comment: using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient;
Non of the above work for some reason.

Comment: @Kobi You are correct. @Joe Sorry, my bad on the reference. From code I have written (this was in DotNet 2.0); System.Net.Mail and then instantiate SmtpClient for use.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to **System.Web** to your project, as well as a `using System.Web.Mail` and see if that helps.  I'd have added this as a comment on qor72's answer, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient;
Non of the above work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For errors 1,2, and 3, instantiate MailMessage like so: MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("string of sender", "string of acceptor");

For error 4, try using the Host property or ServicePoint instead.